# noise() doesn't give me a wide range of values

Tags: java, trigonometry, processing, perlin-noise

I was trying to generate a pseudo-random angle in processing today using noise but it is not working as I would have hoped.

```
float xoff = 0;
float inc = 0.01;

void draw(){
 float vx = cos( noise(xoff) * 2 * PI));
 xoff += inc;
}
```

This is the important part of my code. What I thought would happen was that vx would be a random float between -1 and 1 but it is *almost* always negative. What seems to be the problem is that the noise(xoff) is outputting a limited range of values. Only between 0.3 and 0.7. For vx to be positive it needs to be lower than 0.3 and higher than 0.7, but this never *almost* never happens.

What is going wrong here?

Comment: Are you looking for a uniform distribution in the range [0,1]?  If so, why not just use random()?

Answer (score 1):

You might adjust the [`noiseDetail()`](http://processing.org/reference/noiseDetail_.html) to include more than 4 `octaves` or to use a `falloff` below 0.5.